# How to hide all files in a folder via using terminal or script

Tags: ubuntu, script, gnome-terminal

I have a folder which located as `/home/makgun/Desktop/a\ b` so that

I tried this command `mv /home/makgun/Desktop/a\ b/*  /home/makgun/Desktop/a\ b/.*` to rename all files as `.FILENAME` to be hidden but it didn't work also it deleted all files ( Fortunately, I tried this command with "try folder" and I  copied 2 files to this folder. But after this command they are deleted `not hidden`)

So, What I need to type in command line to hide all files in a folder.

Comment: You have to make a "for loop". Sorry I'm not at my computer so I can't give you the exact command.

Comment: cd to the target directory,  " for f in *; do mv $f .$f ;  done"

Comment: Yes this works but if filename has space character it doesn't work. ( there is a file which is called as `A file` it has space character) How do I do for this type of file?

Comment: Enclose the "$f" and ".$f" in quotes.

Comment: @Zalmy Thanks zalmy for your quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done using a for loop.

Navigate to the target directory. Then run the command below

```
for f in *; do mv "$f"  ".$f" ;  done
```

Comment: I wondered that how I can back to unhide? Because it will be necessary for me after 1 month.

Answer (score 2):

**To unhide the files**
use `for f in .*;do mv "$f" ${f:1}; done`.

Test it first just to make sure it doesn't break anything.

**Explanation**
`for f in .*` creates a loop of all the files starting with `.` to parse the . I used `${f:1}` bash substring function.

Thank you

Comment: By the way, to test, use `for f in .*; do echo mv "$f" "${f:1}"; done`. It is a good practice to test your scripts like that. Then, you can write `done | bash` instead of `done`.